# Import Android Library

Tags: android, import

I want to use a specific Android library in my project. I use Eclipse IDE. When I import the complete library, I clean and build the project.

In the end, there is always an error that the project is missing required `src` Folder gen.

Any ideas how to solve the problem? In a "normal" application, instead of the step "build the project" I use "Run the application" and this problem dis occurs but for libraries it is not available.

Comment: Have you used the "Android/Fixup project" menu entry after importing the project? I generally find I have to do that, restart Eclipse and possibly repeat until it works.

Comment: u shd restart ur eclipse first ,right click on the project -> buildpath->configure buildpath  click on this and see

Comment: If you want to import code in eclipse and getting this error then create new project from that source file

Comment: In the end i had to build it twice, then the gen-Folder was there. The next problem was a build-path-error message where Deepak (next answer) had the right idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well once I had the same problem, sometimes Eclipse does not update properly.
In such a case what I did was to delete the error message from the Problems-View.

This worked for me, hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Clean only when you think that your build is not correct. While cleaning, the folder gen will be deleted. Thats why you get the error.

It has nothing to do with the library. Just skip cleaning and do it only when you really think there is something messed up with your build.

Comment: Now i have a gen-Folder but there is a new error message, that i have to configure the buildpath. But when i open the buildpath no error messages are shown to me. It only shows the message in the problems-View

Comment: You should have the library jar somewhere in your project. Just right click on it (in the explorer view in eclipse) and click on "add to build path". You can add it also using right click on the project -> build path -> configure build path and than add it there

Answer (score 0):

There have been some known bugs with Android libraries. If the default.properties file is read only in the root directory of your project that has been reported as a bug.  This happens when you check in your project to an svn.